# Writing a Bash script pulling every word that is separated by a comma out of a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will read a text file and pull out every word that is followed by a comma on a new line. I tried using `grep` but it prints the whole line that has a comma in it, and I have had the same trouble with `awk`. I have checked the manage for grep, but it seems to be more focused on flags than syntax. This is a normal .txt file, not a CSV there are just commas as appropriate for normal english grammar. Can anyone show me how to set up this script?

For example if the text file contained a list of animals, like so:

> The Veterinary clinic treats the following animals: dogs, cats, and birds

the script would display:

```
dogs,
cats,
```

Comment: What have you tried?  (And why has someone upvoted a question that clearly does not have any code in it?)

Comment: Nothing I had tried had done anything close to what I wanted, `grep -o ','`, then `grep -o '[[:alpha:]],'` and I don't understand `awk` enough to to do anything more than spin my wheels. Thank you for being so helpful Ghoti. I was unsure which of these to mark as correct, as I don't yet understand bash scripting and the corresponding commands well enough to know why the other two wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to know about `grep`'s `-o` parameter (only matching). If you consider a word to be a series of letters separated by spaces than this match will do:

```
grep -o "[a-zA-Z]\+," file
```

Comment: Nope, this will pull out the first occurrence of this pattern on every line of input, not "all the matches" as the OP requires. You'd need to split your input so that individual words are on separate lines, for example by piping through `tr '[[:space:]]' '\n'` before the text hits `grep -o`.

Comment: @ghoti This answer worked just fine when I tested it on a Mac using the OP's example. I.e., it printed all the matches and not just the first occurrence. Were you able to find a counter-example?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of grep supports the `-o` switch then you could use that, otherwise this should work in most versions of awk:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+,$/) print $i }' file
```

Loop through all the fields in the file and print those that consist of only alphabet characters followed by a comma.

If you have GNU awk, then you can simplify the approach by setting `RS` to any number of space characters:

```
awk -v RS='\\s+' '/^[[:alpha:]]+,$/' file
```

Comment: The question mentions "commas as appropriate for normal english grammar". In English, it is not inconceivable that a newline might exist within a sentence: `dogs, cats,\nand birds.` Setting a record separator of just a space will incorrectly match these, and in weird and inconsistent ways. (Try it, it's fun.)

Comment: @ghoti updated to show a potential improvement. I guess there are many ways this approach may fail for different inputs that we haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 0):

And one more with `sed`:

```
#! /bin/sh
sed '
s/[^,]* //g
s/,[^,]*$/,/
s/,\(.\)/,\
\1/g
' <<EOF
The Veterinary clinic treats the following animals: dogs, cats, and birds
EOF
```

How it works:

1. Remove everything not containing a comma but followed by a space.
2. Remove everything not containing a comma following a comma at the end of the line.
3. Replace every comma not being at the end of line with a comma and a new-line.